# Dealing with optional urlparse parameters in url

Tags: python, urlparse

My little script deals with a couple of parameters passed from the url;

```
bright = int(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('bright', None)[0])
loops = int(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('loops', None)[0])
speed = float(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('speed', None)[0])/1000
```

However some of the parameters are optional and sometimes for example 'bright' is not passed in the url since it's not relevant. When thats the case it throws me this error;

```
bright = int(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('bright', None)[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Which I can understand.. it's trying to parse something that's not there. What would be the best way to deal with this? Is there a way to first get a list of the parameters present in the url before trying to parse them?

Comment: Umm... why not just loop over the parameter dictionary you get from `parse_qs` to see the available parameters present in the url?

Comment: Sounds like a plan.. maybe I should give that a shot.. and then some bedtime..

Comment: And you can catch a `None` occurrence with a `try/except` block and act accordingly.

Comment: Yup, that worked.. thanks!

Comment: Unrelated: you're making the same call multiple times: `urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query)` - do it once, store it in a variable, and reuse it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just loop over the parameter dictionary you get from `parse_qs()` to see the available parameters present in the url?

Also, you can catch a `None` occurrence with a `try/except` block, and act accordingly.